# how to write seo-friendly titles where is no space ( in a column box )?

Tags: seo

what is the best way to write long seo-friendly titles in sidebars?

```
<h3 title="My long title, the very seo one">Menu</h3>
OR:
<h3>My long title, the very seo one</h3> // hidden via css
<div class="title">Menu</div>
```

what else? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI, if you're hiding that `<h3>` via CSS in a live site that's called cloaking and will get you banned if you get caught by the search engines doing that.

Your first example is the proper way to do it as that is what the `title` attribute is for. It allows you to provide extra text that gives the user more information about an element. Usually it is used with links but it does apply to headings as well.

Comment: thanks! what about <h3 style="text-overflow:ellipsis">long seo title</h3> ?

Comment: That's perfectly fine although it may awkward for users

Comment: i will show the full title on mouseover! thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

For your SEO, that is not really important (it was in 2001, but that is some time ago).

For your users however, both isn't the best solution. "Menu" or any other generic one-word does not tell the user anything about the content of the section.

Use something like Short title that gives the user a clue about the sections contents and displays more info onmouseover.